# Detect Notification Click

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, accessibilityservice, notificationservices

So I'm in this situation where I have to detect a click on the notification and read its metadata using `AccessibilityService`. For this I'm currently using `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` but it doesn't seem to work. It is not able to capture the click on the notification.

Also I tried using `typeNotificationStateChanged` and `NotificationListenerService` but to no avail as both these don't have methods or functions to detect a click on the notification (I'm not sure though).

Will be glad if anybody could help me out.

Note - The notifications belong to other apps and not built by my app.

**What I want -**

-> Detect a **click** on notification and extract details like title, message etc.

**What I don't want -**

-> Detect an incoming notification

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are building the notification by yourself, or using a service like FCM?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv The notifications are not built by me. They belong to other apps. Like if my app is "A", and my app is trying to detect notification click of app "B".